# Angular Material buttons height

Tags: javascript, angularjs, material-design

html:

```
<body id="app">
  <md-button>
    Yo
  </md-button>
</body>
```

Looks:
[image: angular material button 100% height]

Why button with 100% height? But at materials docs they looks [like inline element](https://material.angularjs.org/#/demo/material.components.button).

And material directives without replace option:

[image]

But at materials docs all directives replaced with templates.

What is wrong?

Comment: I have the exact same issue...

Comment: @Shprink I cloned angular material repository and built it. And build result I added to my application (css and js ) and all became ok. Seems something wrong with their bower?

Answer (score 3):

You are probably using an old version. Angular-material is in heavy development. Also you may want to try using `layout="horizontal"` (note in 0.6.0-rc1 `horizontal` has changed to `row`) on your body element so that it is displayed right. Try reading the layout [docs](https://material.angularjs.org/#/layout/container)

If you have a plunkr I could probably help you out more but I hope the above solves your problems.

Comment: Fixed in 0.6 indeed. Thanks!